# Filter on annotated column in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I have two models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    ...

class StateChange(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(default=now, db_index=True)
    project = models.ForeignKey("project.Project")
    state = models.IntegerField(choices=PROJECT_STATE_TYPES, db_index=True)
    ...
```

The models are linked and I need a list of projects which is filtered by the related StateChange if there's one. 
I build my queryset like this:

```
state_checked = Case(
    When(statechange__state=PROJECT_STATE_CHECKED, then=F('statechange__created_at'))
)
state_construction_ordered = Case(
    When(statechange__state=PROJECT_STATE_CONSTRUCTION_ORDERED, then=F('statechange__created_at'))
)
qs = Projekt.objects.visible_for_me(self.request.user) \
    .annotate(date_reached_state_checked=state_checked) \
    .annotate(date_reached_state_construction_ordered=state_construction_ordered)\
    .exclude(Q(date_reached_state_checked__isnull=True) & Q(statechange__state=PROJECT_STATE_CHECKED) |
             Q(date_reached_state_construction_ordered__isnull=True) & Q(statechange__state=PROJECT_STATE_CONSTRUCTION_ORDERED))
```

The Project may have no matching StateChange, or one or both.

I need the list to show one Project-line in all cases. My queryset only works for zero or one matching StateChange. It excludes the Projects where both StateChanges are present and I see why it does it when I look at the generated query.

If I do not exclude anything, it shows 1 line for each case.

Can anyone give me a hint about how to make django create the JOINs I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did it by using .extra():

```
return Projekt.objects.all().extra(
    select={
        "date_reached_state_checked": "SELECT created_at FROM tracking_statechange WHERE tracking_statechange.projekt_id = projekt_projekt.id AND tracking_statechange.state = 20",
        "date_reached_state_construction_ordered": "SELECT created_at FROM tracking_statechange WHERE tracking_statechange.projekt_id = projekt_projekt.id AND tracking_statewechsel.state = 50"
    })
```